# Two div in column without table

Tags: html, css

Is it possible without table tag or display: table?

https://monosnap.com/file/MoxMr7WehKJD4RyKWPTJ7Dyqg8dsez

```
 <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="title">Some title</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
 </div>

.wrapper {
    border: 3px solid yellow;
    width: 250px;
    height: 350px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    background: green;
}
.title {
    min-height: 30px;
    max-height: 80px;
    background: blue;
}
.content {
    background: red;
    height: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wqozs28y/

Ill try it with position absolute, but i donw know what will be the height on TITLE div :(

Comment: Yes it is possible. Is that the answer you were looking for?

Comment: @Andrew sorry dude. My english is so bad. It is very difficult to create a good question. ofc ill need HOW it possible :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use `flexbox` depending on what level of browser support you want.

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 3px solid yellow;
  width: 250px;
  height: 350px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.title {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;
  min-height: 30px;
  max-height: 80px;
  background: blue;
}
.content {
  background: red;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="title">Some title</div>
  <div class="content">Content</div>
</div>
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/w1hnsLz8/2/)

Comment: That's almost what I need. but title div (blue) already have 80 height, i need only when content. like this - http://jsfiddle.net/wqozs28y/2/
flex-basis: 30px; not working?